# How can I check that the computed eigenpairs are correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, matrix-decomposition

If I use a C++ library to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a somewhat large matrix, (about dimension of 50), then is there a quick way to confirm that the computed eigenvalues and eigenvectors are correct?

So far, the dot products between eigenvectors are zeros and is that sufficient to confirm that they are correct?

(Or is Eigendecomposition the only way? the problem with that is when the dimension gets bigger and the computation time becomes non-negligible)

Comment: Why not just multiply the matrix by the claimed eigenvectors and check that the result is the eigenvalue times the eigenvector?  You have to worry about precision, but that is true for any approach.

Comment: Or reconstruct the matrix from the claimed decomposition, and check its accuracy.  I always do that because I always confuse the matrix of eigenvectors with its transpose, and thus debug my understanding of what the calling sequence really means.

Comment: anything that we know about the matrix? is it symmetric? do you just want to verify if you have computed a correct eigenpair or do you want to check if you have found all the eigenpair?

Comment: Most of the time, I will be dealing with a large real symmetric sparse matrix, and needs to check if all the pairs are correct.

Comment: I heard there's a library that allows me to quickly do matrix operations for large sparse matrix, so even if the size goes to 25,000 I suppose it wouldn't be that too time consuming. Will check to see the total run time tho

Comment: If the matrix is symmetric, then you will have orthogonal eigenvectors, but otherwise there’s no reason to expect that their pairwise dot products are zero.